# Add more attributes to json entries

Tags: php, encoding, json

I have a json file based on data gathered from facebook, specifically likes. Now, the way I am doing this is basic:

```
  $likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=5000'), 'data', array());
 fwrite($fileout, json_encode($likes));
```

And my resulting json file has the entries structured like it follows:

```
{"category":"Athlete","name":"Anatoly Karpov","id":"152323494906"}
```

The problem is that in my json there will also stored data like "friends" or "groups" and I want to easily differentiate them, so what I would like to do is to add another attribute in the json file, "type"="like" or "friend" for example. Does anyone have an idea how can I do it as efficient as possible?
Thanks to user Wrikken, the problem is solved:

```
 foreach($likes as $key=>$like)
{$likes[$key]['type']='like';}   
fwrite($fileout,json_encode($likes);
```

Comment: open,decode,add value,encode,save (or add value before first encode & save to begin with).

Comment: :( so just as I expected. I'll add some code about how I am thinking to do it

Comment: @Wrikken Please take a look at the code. Do you think it might work?

Comment: WTH? Why add non-json to json? Just `foreach($likes as $key=>$like){$likes[$key]['type']='like';} fwrite($fileout,json_encode($likes);` & you're done.

Comment: @Wrikken I am quite a newbie in this. Okay, so will the sequence above add all my data in the $likes array, plus for each, add the attribute "type" with the value of "like" ?

Comment: All your data _is_ already in the the `$likes` array, and the code in my comment will add the type attribute to every single item in there yes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add it to the array before you json_encode/write it, like so:

```
$likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=5000'), 'data', array());

foreach ($likes as $key => $like) {
    $likes[$key]['type'] = 'like';
}

fwrite($fileout, json_encode($likes));
```